# as3 air File.File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath - check when loaded

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, air, loaded

I am trying to load folder names into an array for later use. It works fine on my desktop but when I test it on a mobile device (**both Android and iPhone**) and it is calling another function -  displayFlags();  - before I get the folder names into an array.

displayFlags() needs this array of names to work and I am getting errors from this line in of code in displayFlags(); Again its because the array is empty.

flag.load(new URLRequest(LangPath[i] + "/flag.png"));

Below is the code that loads file and the array. 
**Is there a way to check when the array is available and call a function after its loaded?**

```
var folderLanguages:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("Languages");

var availLang:Array = folderLanguages.getDirectoryListing();
var Lang:Array;
var LangPath:Array;
var flagButton:MovieClip;


function getLang(evt:Event = null)
{
Lang = new Array();
LangPath = new Array();
for (var i:uint = 0; i < availLang.length; i++)
   {

   if(availLang[i].isDirectory)
         {
        //trace(availLang[i].name);// gets the name
        Lang.push(availLang[i].name);
        LangPath.push(availLang[i].nativePath);
        trace(availLang[i].nativePath);// gets the name

         }
   }

displayFlags();
}
```

Comment: There's no reason that doesn't work. `getDirectoryListing()` is not asynchronous so it is populated before the other code runs. The only thing I can think of is that you are using `applicationDirectory` which I have always had trouble using on iOS (you don't clarify the system you are using)

Comment: It's having issues on both Droid and IOS

Comment: What I need is some sort of loader that can be used with this line: var availLang:Array = folderLanguages.getDirectoryListing();    or the loop below.

Comment: No, you don't need that. `getDirectoryListing()` is synchronous, meaning no other synchronous code (which is 99% of AS3) will run at the same time as it. So the directory listing is properly populating. Is the array null after calling getDirectoryListing() or is it just empty? If it is empty, my guess is that it is an issue with using `applicationDirectory` as opposed to `applicationStorageDirectory`

Comment: Well it's not empty on my computer but empty on my Android. On the IOS I can't seem to debug from USB anymore. Not sure why but when I open it on IOS it doesn't work as well but I can't see errors.

Comment: Again, I don't know if you can use applicationDirectory like that on mobile. You are supposed to use applicationStorageDirectory.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30604/discussion-between-papa-de-beau-and-josh-janusch)

Comment: I figured out the issue. I spent a whole day on this. It was a lower case letter that was supposed to be CAPS in the URL. Why did this work on the DESKTOP and not on my phones I don't know. It's too bad. No sign of the reason why the error. What a waste of time.